# Permissions broken after mounting disk on /home in Linux VM with AAD integration

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machines

My problem is as following:

I have a Azure Linux VM and external Managed Disk attached to it. I want to mount this disk to /home directory so that files of my users are persistent across operation of upgrading image of this VM. Upgrade requires the VM to be deleted and recreated with new image from Terraform code (with current setup).

So what I am doing right now: lsblk (to find the disk name, let's say it's sdc)

sudo parted /dev/sdc --script mklabel gpt mkpart xfspart xfs 0% 100%

sudo partprobe /dev/sdc

sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdc1

sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /home

And then I am also adding an entry in /etc/fstab to make this persistent:

**echo "UUID=33333333-3b3b-3c3c-3d3d-3e3e3e3e3e3e /home xfs defaults,nofail 1 2" >> /etc/fstab**

The problem is that after the mount process the users don't have required permissions in home directory as they had before. The AAD integration is trying to create /home/[user] directory for each user that logs in but it's not able to put them in there because of lack of permissions. x

What can I do about it? To setup it once for it to work instead of running chown,chmod command for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting a disk directly to /home in Linux is not recommended because /home is typically the location for user home directories, configuration files, and personal data. If you mount a disk directly to /home, it will likely overwrite existing user data and configuration files, causing potential data loss and system instability.

So you need to unmount, the mount you made to /home.

If possible I would mount it something else that doesn't exist already as a system folder, I personally use /data

You could create a folder inside home and mount in to there.

And by the way how do you know a mounted disk isn't touched when upgrading a VM? I don't exactly how your upgrade process works but be aware of that.
I think it would be safer instead of mounting a disk, mounting an azure file share with nfs or blobfuse2 for example.

And upgrades can go wrong, so make sure before doing a upgrade make a backup. I realize I added some off topic advice, but I hope it's helpful for you